# Using style in AndroidView Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How can we use style property inside AndroidView in Compose? The below code snippet doesn't work.

```
 AndroidView(factory = { context ->
                Button(context).apply {
                     text = "Turn On"
                     style = "@style/button_style"     
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"@style/button_style"` can only be used inside XML.

When you set styles/colors/drawables and other resources form code, you need to use `R.style.button_style` instead.

Also android `android.widget.Button` doesn't have `style` parameter, but you can pass it with a context into the initializer, like this:

```
AndroidView(factory = { context ->
    val style = R.style.GreenText
    android.widget.Button(ContextThemeWrapper(context, style), null, style).apply {
        text = "Turn On"

    }
})
```

**UPDATE:** here's a more detailed example of `AndroidView` usage. You can set initial values during `factory`, and you can update your view state depending on Compose state variables inside `update` block

```
var flag by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Switch(checked = flag, onCheckedChange = { flag = !flag })
AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        val style = R.style.GreenText
        android.widget.Button(ContextThemeWrapper(context, style), null, style).apply {
            text = "Turn On"
            // set initial text color from resources
            setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black))
        }
    },
    update = { button ->
        // set dynamic color while updating 
        // depending on a state variable
        button.setTextColor((if (flag) Color.Red else Color.Black).toArgb())
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Philip. Also, do you know how we can use other android attributes like android:textcolor etc. inside AndroidView composable

Comment: @AndroidNewcomer If you need to update some xml view, I suggest you looking for an existing non Compose solution and applying it to the view. I've added sample of changing text color. Also `AndroidView` should be used when you already have some views with old layout and don't wanna convert them to compose. From your questions it seems like you wanna build them from scratch: in this case I suggest you building views using Compose methods instead of using `AndroidView`. Like compose `Button` will take much less code to get the same effect.

Comment: I have a library that is currently in xml only and I want to use it with Compose

setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, **R.color.black**))
Here we cannot use MaterialTheme colors right, like MaterialTheme.colors.primary?

Comment: @AndroidNewcomer you can convert compose color for old views with `MaterialTheme.colors.primary.toArgb()`, same as I did in `update`